# How can I convert a string (YYYY.MM) to a date format (MM/YYYY) that excel will understand for graphing purposes?

Tags: excel, date

Currently my excel sheet has columns of strings in the Date column (example of 1871.01, 1871.02 etc). I would like to convert these to MM/YYYY date format so that I may chart the data in a time series format. I've tried this

```
=(RIGHT(A9,2)&LEFT(A9,4))
```

but it just spits out mmyyyy and not in a date format. When I try to format the new cell as a date it does nothing. Any help?

Comment: Excel dates are just sequential serial numbers; 1 = January 1, 1900, so you can't have a date from 1871.

Comment: `=RIGHT(A9,2) & "/" & LEFT(A9,4)`

Comment: @Vitalizzare Sir, that will still return as `Text`, may be OP look into this to work on [pre 1900 dates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/pre-1900-dates/m-p/129999)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Right. That's a good point!

Comment: @Vitalizzare That actually worked, except for one small issue. Now a number like 1885.1 (which is supposed to represent the 10th month) is now showing as .1/1885 in the converted date box. Is there any work around for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel cannot represent dates before 1900. That's why some clever person has used the text format `1871.01` to represent January 1871. You can use this in charts to plot the date in a category (not a date) axis.

If you do want to use a time axis you may want to approach it like this:

- extract the year part and add 100
- extract the month part and build a date that is 100 years after the date shown
- plot the data with the new date in a scatter chart (not a line chart)
- in the worksheet, generate a range of dates for the date range of the chart and corresponding 0 values
- create a helper cell for labels that show the 1800 equivalent date as text in the desired format
- add the helper series to the chart
- remove the chart x axis labels
- add labels to the helper series with "Values from cells" and position "below"
- format the helper series to have no line and no marker (still visible in the screenshot.

With this method you can place as many or as few fake X axis labels as you like, by creating or removing values in the helper for label cells in the grid.

It is a bit more setup than plotting dates after 1900 in a timeline, but it can totally be done.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.